Calculate daily sales growth percentage
I have a table in my PieCloudDB Database that stores daily sales (Some dates may not have data), and I now want to calculate the daily sales growth percentage for consecutive dates.
Suppose I have the following data:



date
sales




2024-01-01
1500


2024-01-02
1400


2024-01-03
1600


2024-01-04
2000


2024-02-02
1100


2024-02-03
1100


2024-02-04
1500



I want to get result like this:



date
sales
daily_growth_percentage




2024-01-01
1500



2024-01-02
1400
-6.67%


2024-01-03
1600
14.29%


2024-01-04
2000
25.00%


2024-02-02
1100



2024-02-03
1100
0.00%


2024-02-04
1500
36.36%



Below is my query:
WITH PreviousSales AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        sales,
        LAG(sales) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS previous_sales
    FROM Sales
)
SELECT
    date,
    sales,
    CASE
        WHEN previous_sales IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN previous_sales = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE ROUND(((sales - previous_sales)/ previous_sales) * 100, 2)|| '%'
    END AS daily_growth_percentage
FROM PreviousSales;

But the results I got were all 0, and the result should not be output on 2024-02-02 (there is no data on 02-01 in the table, so NULL should be output)



date
sales
daily_growth_percentage




2024-01-01
1500



2024-01-02
1400
0.00%


2024-01-03
1600
0.00%


2024-01-04
2000
0.00%


2024-02-02
1100
0.00%


2024-02-03
1100
0.00%


2024-02-04
1500
0.00%



How to get the right result?

I found the reason of the problem. The data type of the sales in my PieCloudDB is int. When doing division, the result less than 1 will become 0, after converting (sales - previous_sales) to numeric, the correct result will be output.
Then about the output results on 2024-02-02, just need to partition them by year and month and it will be solved.
So the correct query is as follows:
WITH PreviousSales AS (
    SELECT
        date,
        sales,
        LAG(sales) OVER (
            PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
            ORDER BY date
        ) AS previous_sales
    FROM Sales
)
SELECT
    date,
    sales,
    CASE
        WHEN previous_sales IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN previous_sales = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE ROUND(((sales - previous_sales)::numeric / previous_sales) * 100, 2)|| '%'
    END AS daily_growth_percentage
FROM PreviousSales;

